# On how to use phpexcel reader

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I get the values from a cell using php reader.. All of those tutorials in the internet just generates errors in my code and I can't find a reliable site to help me.

Example I have cell Name and under it are names... How can I get the names and store them in an array? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("yourfile.xlsx");


$value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();

echo 'The Value is: '.$value;
```